# Windows freezes at startup & cannot start sptd

Tags: windows, drivers, event-viewer

Recently right after I enter the Windows password, the computer froze at welcome screen, I then entered Safe Mode to restore system and then everything works fine

But today I started computer again and the same problem re-appeared. I decided to look carefully at **Event Viewer** in safe mode and get the error:

```
Driver detected an internal error in its data structures
Source sptd
Event ID 4
```

I followed some instructions on the Internet and uninstalled Daemon Tools Lite, right after that I restarted Windows normally, then everything works fine again

I want to know that what has been happening to the sptd driver, what to do to fix this problem permanently and how I can use any other CD ROM emulator?

Note that I installed Daemon Tools for a very long time without error until recent days, it good though. As writing this topic, I did not install any CD ROM emulator since I think the problem will occurred again if I do so, I will wait for help from you guys

Comment: You suspected correctly.